# Uncountable intersection of nondecreasing family of sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing

Motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484710/measurability-and-almost-sure-convergence) question, consider a nondecreasing family of sets $(A_t)_{t\gt0}$, that is, assume that $A_t\subseteq A_s$ for every positive $t\leqslant s$. I want to show that for every strictly positive sequence $(a_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $0$, we have:$$
\bigcap_{t\gt0}A_t=\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{a_m}.
$$

**My try:** It's obvious that, $$\bigcap_{t\gt0}A_t \subseteq \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{a_m}$$ holds since in LHS we are taking the intersection of more sets than RHS. Now suppose that, $$x \in  \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty A_{a_m}.$$ This means $$\forall m \in \mathbb{N} \ \ x\in A_{a_m},$$ and we should prove $$\forall t \gt 0 \ \ x\in A_t.$$ Consider an arbitrary $t\gt 0$. Since we know $a_m \to 0$, we can find $K\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m\ge K$ we have $|a_m - 0| = a_m \le t$. Therefore, since the family of sets $(A_t)_{t\gt0}$ is nondecreasing, we have: $$\forall m\ge K \ \ A_{a_m} \subseteq A_t.$$By assumption, for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ we know $x \in A_{a_m}$ and this implies that $x \in A_t$. Note that this procedure can be done for every $t \gt 0$, and so $$x \in \bigcap_{t\gt0}A_t.$$

**Question:** Is my reasoning correct? Also can the conditions for the sequence $(a_m)_{m=1}^{\infty}$ be somewhat relaxed? I mean the conditions $a_m \to 0$ and $\forall m \in \mathbb{N} \ \ a_m  \gt 0$. It seems to me that they are necessary and can't be relaxed.

Comment: You've got an inclusion sign mixed up. You want $s\leq t\implies A_s\leq A_t$; otherwise, $a_m\leq t$ implies $A_t\subseteq A_{a_m}$, not the other way around.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks. I think it's correct now.

Comment: The conditions can certainly be relaxed. The sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ for odd $n$ and $a_n=1$ for even $n$ would also have the property, even though it does not converge to $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, and it is a special case of a more general result. In fact you don't need the sequence to converge to $0$. You just need $0$ to be a limit point, so that for every $t\gt 0$ there exists $m$ such that $a_m\leq t$.

Let $(P,\preceq)$ be a partially ordered set. A subset $S$ of $P$ is *cofinal in $P$* if and only if for every $x\in P$ there exists $s\in S$ such that $x\preceq s$.

**Theorem.** Let $(P,\preceq)$ be a partially ordered set, and let $(A_x)_{x\in P}$ be a family of sets such that $x\preceq y\implies A_y\subseteq A_x$. If $S$ is a cofinal subset of $P$, then
$$\bigcap_{x\in P}A_x = \bigcap_{s\in S}A_s.$$

*Proof.* Since $S\subseteq P$, then we necessarily have
$$\bigcap_{x\in P}A_x\subseteq \bigcap_{s\in S}A_s.$$
For the converse inclusion, let $a\in\bigcap_{s\in S}A_s$; we want to show that $a\in A_x$ for all $x\in P$. To that end, let $x\in P$. By cofinality of $S$, there exists $t\in S$ such that $x\preceq t$. By assumption, that means that $A_t\subseteq A_x$. Then
$$a \in \bigcap_{s\in S}A_s \subseteq A_t \subseteq A_x.$$
Therefore, $a\in A_x$ for all $x\in P$, which proves the desired result. $\Box$

(In fact, *this* is a special case of an even *more* general result that limits and colimits from a poset can be taken over a cofinal subset)

Your result follows by taking $P = (0,\infty)$ under the reverse order (so that $s\preceq t$ if and only if $t\leq s$ under the usual order); and $S=(a_m)$. Because $\lim a_m=0$, then  $S$ is cofinal in $P$: given any $t\gt 0$, there exists $m$ such that $a_m\leq t$, and therefore $t\preceq a_m$. Thus, for every $t\in (P,\preceq)$ there exists $s\in S$ such that $t\preceq s$. And because we have that $t\leq s$ implies $A_t\subseteq A_s$, we get the desired condition that $x\preceq y\implies A_y\subseteq A_x$.

So you just need the sequence to be "cofinal". In this case, that means that you need it to satisfy that for every $t\gt 0$ there exists $m$ such that $a_m\leq t$. This is equivalent to asking that $\liminf a_m = 0$.

To see that you must have $(a_m)$ be cofinal to be able to conclude the result in generality (so that no weaker condition will do), consider your set-up with $A_t=[0,t)$. Then $\cap_{x\in P}A_x = \{0\}$. But if there exists $t$ such that for all $m$, $a_m\gt t$, then $[0,t)\subseteq \cap_{m=1}^{\infty}A_{a_m}$, so you do not get equality in that case.

---

**Added.** In light of the question in the comment:

**Proposition.** Let $(a_m)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers. The following are equivalent:

1. $\{a_m\mid m\geq 1\}$ is cofinal in $(0,\infty)$ under the reverse order.
2. $\liminf a_m = 0$.
3. For every $t\gt 0$ there exists $m\geq 1$ such that $a_m\leq t$.
4. For every $t\gt 0$ and every $N>0$ there exists $m\geq N$ such that $a_m\leq t$.

We use the following characterization of the limit inferior of a sequence:

> The limit inferior of $(a_m)$ is the infimum of the set of real numbers $r$ for which there exists a subsequence $(a_{m_k})$ of $(a_m)$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{m_k}=r$.

*Proof of the proposition.*

1$\iff$3 is the definition of cofinality.

1$\implies$4 Assume $\{a_m\}$ is cofinal under the reverse order, and let $t\gt 0$, $N>0$. Let $r=\frac{1}{2}\min(a_1,\ldots,a_N,t)$. This is positive, so by cofinality of $\{a_m\}$, there exists $m$ such that $a_m\leq r$. But since $r\lt a_i$ for $1\leq i\leq N$, we mus thave $m\geq N$. And since $r\leq t$, we have found $m\geq N$ such that $a_m\leq r \leq t$, as required.

4$\implies$3 is immediate, by taking $N=1$.

2$\implies$3 Let $t\gt 0$. Since $\liminf a_n=0$, there exists a subsequence $(a_{m_k})$ of $(a_m)$ such that $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{m_k}$ exists and $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{m_k}\leq  \frac{t}{2}$. Therefore, there exists $K$ such that for all $k\geq K$, $|a_{m_k}-\frac{t}{2}|\lt \frac{t}{4}$. In particular, $a_{m_{K}}\leq \frac{3t}{4}$, so there exists $a_{m_{K}}\leq t$, proving 3 holds.

4$\implies$2: We inductively construct a subsequence that converges to $0$. By 4, there exist $m_1\geq 1$ such that $a_{m_1}\leq 1$. There exists $m_2\geq m_1$ such that $a_{m_2}\leq\frac{1}{2}$. Assuming we have defined $m_k\geq m_{k-1}$ such that $a_{m_k}\leq \frac{1}{k}$, by 4 there exists $m_{k+1}\geq m_k$ such that $a_{m_{k+1}}\leq \frac{1}{k+1}$.

Thus we have a subsequence $(a_{m_k})$ such that $0\leq a_{m_k}\leq \frac{1}{k}$ for all $k$; by the Squeeze Theorem, $\lim_{k\to\infty}a_{m_k}$ exists and is $0$. Since there is a subsequence that converges to $0$, it follows that $\liminf a_m\leq 0$. However, all $a_m$ are positive, so every subsequence is bounded below by $0$. Thus, the limit of any subsequence of $(a_m)$ is nonnegative, so $\liminf a_m\geq 0$. Thus, $\liminf a_m=0$, proving 2.

This proves the equivalences $\Box$

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks! Just one question. Why are $(a_m)$ be cofinal and $\liminf a_m = 0$ equivalent in this case? It seems to me that $\liminf a_m = 0$ is an stronger condition since it requires that for every $t\gt0$ there exists $N$ such that $a_m \le t$ **for all** $m \ge N$ not just $a_N \le t$. Sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: @S.H.W You are misinterpreting the limit inferior. The limit inferior is (among other characterizations) the infimum of all limits of subsequences of $(a_m)$. So in this case it just requires that for all $t\gt 0$ and $N\gt 0$ there exist **at least one** $m\geq N$ such that $a_m\leq t$, not "for all $m\geq N$". And this is equivalent to the condition I gave, i.e. that it be cofinal under the inverse order.

Comment: @S.H.W I have added a proof that the conditions I gave are equivalent.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the bad mistake. Now I understand that they are indeed equivalent and the minimum condition is $\liminf a_m = 0$. I really appreciate your help, thanks.